# Store Korean,Chinese, Japanese and English characters in one table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to store data that contains Korean,Chinese, Japanese and English characters in different rows in a single table. Since we plan to group by column that contains all of the languages listed above, we need to make sure that values remain completely unchanged in database and when we output them. 
Is there a Collation or storage type that will support this kind of operation?

if not, can I create different tables with different Collations and union them in a View to produce correct results, or should I be looking at a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to change default charset to `utf8mb4` and make PDO connection use it as well.